# Jellybean/ICS Android HTTP Post Method + WebView.RestoreState

Tags: android, webview, http-post

I'm using the API 17 emulator to test a page containing a web view.

1. The webview first loads a page using the GET method.
2. Then the user submits the web form using HTTP POST method which causes a second page to load.
3. At this point if I rotate the screen I receive the "Webpage not available" error seen below.  This only occurs if the page was loaded using the POST method.  Note: I'm trying to restore the webview's state using webview.restoreState (see code below).  Is there any way to tell Android to re-post the form data and reload the page instead of displaying this error message?!

I can't reproduce this same issue on KitKat, Lollipop, or Gingerbread... I can only reproduce this issue on Jellybean and Ice Cream Sandwich so far...

I've also confirmed this is an issue on an actual Nexus 7 device running Jellybean, so it's not an emulator-only problem.

**Note:** I'm not particularly interesting in using something like android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden".  As I understand it, this might solve my rotation issues, but the problem may still resurface if the activity state needs to be restored for other reasons.

### **Screenshots:**

**Step #1: Load the WebView Normally**

[image: Step 1]

**Step #2: Submit the Form (uses HTTP Post Method)**

[image: Step 2]

**Step #3: Rotate the screen to trigger webview.restoreState - error occurs**

[image: Step 3]

### **Code:**

Here is some sample code to go along with my question.  The code is in Mono C# but should be very nearly identical to Java.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    WebView webview;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        webview = new WebView(this);
        SetContentView(webview);

        if (bundle == null)
            webview.LoadUrl("http://2-dot-npwc-services.appspot.com/test-post.jsp");
        else
            webview.RestoreState(bundle);
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        webview.SaveState(bundle);
    }
}
```

The sample HTML page that is performing the POST method looks like this:

```
<html>
<form action="test-post.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test" value="test"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<p>You entered: <%=request.getParameter("test")%></p>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying an id to the WebView widget? I don't know if it helps but I know that if a widget does not have an associated id with it, Android does not persist what it holds through configuration changes. In earlier versions this used to lead to weird errors. Maybe that is what you are seeing?

Comment: You can supply any id. Can you let us know what you find?

Comment: I've tried it both ways.  I get the same error even when supplying the webview an id (i inflated the webview from a layout)

Comment: Just an fyi.. from Android 4.4 and later, WebView is based off Blink. Before that, it was based on the WebKit rendering engine.

Comment: Yea that may be part of the issue.  Although I'd still like to fix it regardless, if possible.  Also I think it's a little strange that I don't encounter the issue on Gingerbread.

Comment: If you are ok with workarounds, I would suggest that you have an if-else clause and depending on whether the framework is below or above a certain level, do the POST operation again. This should get you working. On a sidenote, do you have javascript content rendering in the page that is not being displayed properly?

Comment: I don't think I can easily do a workaround because there are many web pages involved and I don't necessarily know what data should be reposted.  We advised client that there may be problems using webviews like this but they want to move forward.  There is no javascript involved in the page where I'm encountering the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The browser it's doing good (although it's a pain for us), you have 2 ways:

1- Keeping the webView instance and restoring the state, adding like you said *android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"*

2- Or reloading the post petition again.

I take the first one and if i get some error, i will go back to the last page. Doing static content, so on rotation no network or a new petition it's needed on each rotation, which if not, on server side will be a pain too.

To achieve the "if error go back" you need to set a Custom WebClient and override this method

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        if ( webView.canGoBack() ) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.error_web, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           webView.goBack();
        }
    }
});
```

You can filter by errorCode to go back when you want, in some kind of error you can go back on other do other thing. I dont' know which error raises this POST request or if you want more filter on other situations, so i'm sure you can do a fine grain filter using it.

Edit: You have here the possible error codes
[WebViewClient Error Codes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  FYI, The errorCode is Android.Webkit.ClientError.Connect - Couldn't connect to the server.